# How to send value to javascript function when fire asp.net button?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I'm write this code for client side:

```
<script>
    function initialize(x, y) {
        alert(x);
        alert(y);
        var mapProp = {


            center: new google.maps.LatLng(x, y),
            zoom: 7,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), mapProp);
    }

    function loadScript() {
        var script = document.createElement("script");
        script.type = "text/javascript";
        script.src = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=&sensor=false&callback=initialize";
        document.body.appendChild(script);
    }

    window.onload = loadScript;
</script>
```

and this code for server side with asp.net:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "calljs", "initialize(" + "45.508742" + ", " + "-0.120850" + ");", true);
}
```

but when i run this code value send to function,but in this line not work:

```
center: new google.maps.LatLng(x, y)
```

when i change up line to this:

```
center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.4323,-0.12332)
```

it's work!,how can i solve that?

Comment: **How** doesn't it work? What happens?

Comment: thanks my friend,no show position to me in google map!,but when i enter value for lang and lat manually ,it's work,but when i send value with asp button click event,not work!

Comment: Have you tried looking at the console in F12 developer tools? Also, is this something you can do in a client-side button click event?

Comment: @elnazirani _not work_: any error? do nothing? not calling function?

Comment: No,how can i look console in vs 2013?

Comment: @Grundy no show me any error,but no show me position on map!

Comment: in what browser you run it?

Comment: Press F12 to look in console in your browser, to see what javascript, if any, the browser is running.

Comment: you have the alert in your function. do u get the alert?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use the OnClientClick attribute on your asp.net button:

```
<asp:button id="Button1" text="Show location" OnClientClick="initialize(51.4323,-0.12332); return false" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" />
```

The RegisterStartupScript isn't the best way to setup clientside click events.

Comment: But i want send the value from textbox, for examle when fire the button,send text1 and text2 value to initialize argumants.

Comment: You also can read the values client side like: `var textbox1value = $get('<%=textbox1.ClientID%>').value;`